# Server call timeout because of Accept Language header

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have a LAMP server running a web service. It is working well but a monitoring service of one of my customers reports that my server does not return when it is called.

I narrowed the problem to this: 
When the call includes

> "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5"

it works  but with

> "Accept-Language:
>   en-us,es-ES_tradnl;q=0.5"

it does not work - the call to the server does not return until it is timed out.

How can I make my apache 2.2.3 (CentOS) not fail because of Accept-Language issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call is not valid by HTTP1.1 spec (accept lang param should be up to 8 chars long) So the solution was to change the header in the sender side and not on my server.